# What limitations are there when solving Singular Value Decomposition on a numeric library (computational)?

Tags: c#, math, linear-algebra

I am using Math.NET' Singular Decomposition to do PCA Analysis on some database. Depending o the amount of columns and rows, the algorithm keeps running indefinetly (so I am assuming it is not converging).

I think Math.NET's implementation of SVD is based on LAPACK.

So I'm wondering if are there any kind of limitation in this algorithm or the characteristics of my data set that could cause this.

PS.: the data doesn't appear to have much covariance between each attribute.

Comment: How large a dataset?  What size is the matrix?

Comment: More than aprox. 70 cols and 70 rows I get no convergence.

Answer (score 1):

With most (if not all) algorithms for computing the singular value decomposition, there is no guarantee that the algorithm will terminate, though it is extremely rare that it does not. Good implementations, like LAPACK, will stop after a certain number of iterations and return an error.

In your case, with matrices of size around 100 (I assume when you say more than approx. 70 you mean not very much more), it should take at most a few seconds to compute the SVD. If it takes longer, your matrix is perhaps one of the extreme rare cases where the algorithm that the library uses does not converge. I'd say it's more likely that you found a bug, in which case you should probably contact the maintainers of the library.